# ffmpeg: overlay multiple images to a video

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

In order to **overlay** a *single* image to a video, I can do:

```
ffmpeg  -i vid00.mp4 -i img00.png  -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t, 1,  2)'"  -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 20  -c:a copy  -y vid01.mp4
```

How can I overlay **multiple** images to a video in a single `ffmpeg` call?

I've tried stuff like:

```
ffmpeg  -i vid00.mp4 -i img00.png -i img01.png  -filter_complex  "\
[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,   1,  2)'[v0]; \
[2:v][3:v]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,   3,  4)'[v1]; \
[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]"  -map 0:a  -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 20  -c:a copy  -y vid01.mp4
```

and variations thereof (by messing with the `[0:v][1:v]` indices),  but to avail.,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i vid00.mp4 -i img00.png -i img00.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t, 1,  2)'[v0];[v0][2:v]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,   3,  4)'" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 20  -c:a copy -y vid01.mp4
```